# How do you make a javascript function that will show text based on a selected option in HTML?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function that changes what text is on a page depending on what is selected from a dropdown. I want it to be onchange, so it switches whenever you pick an option. I made a loop that goes through all of the options, but when I tested it, it always displays the last option, no matter what is selected. The project I'm working on is going to have a lot more information, but I need it to work before I do all that. Also, I'm pretty new at this, so I'm only familiar with vanilla js, and I don't know how all of the other js technologies work.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  var events = document.getElementById('events'),
    event, i;

  for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    event = events[i];
    if (event.value == "Major") {
      text.innerHTML = "majorevents";
    } else if (event.value == "Event1") {
      text.innerHTML = "event 1";
    } else if (event.value == "Event2") {
      text.innerHTML = "event 2";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="events" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="Major">Major Events</option>
  <option value="Event1">1st event</option>
  <option value="Event2">2nd event</option>
</select>
<p id="text"></p>
```

Comment: If any of the answers below answered your question please don't forget to **[mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)** by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or anyone else's) as correct, though marking a question as resolved helps keep things flowing smoothly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop will loop through all `<option>` in your `<select>`. As `"Event2"` is the last option tag, it will set the `innerHTML` to that event. Instead, you only need to get the currently selected `<option>`, so there is no need to use a `for` loop. To do this, you can use `this.value` (by passing `this` into your `onchange` callback), which will give you the value of the selected option.

Also, since you are only adding text to your page (not html), it's more suitable for you to use `.innerText` or `.textContent` rather than `.innerHTML` (as you only need to use that when adding HTML strings)

```js
var text = document.getElementById("text"); // move outside of callback function (no need to get this eleemnt everytime you change your dropdown selection)
function myFunction(element) {
  var event = element.value; // get the value of the select option
  console.log(event);
  if (event === "Major") {
    text.innerText = "majorevents";
  } else if (event === "Event1") {
    text.innerText = "event 1";
  } else if (event === "Event2") {
    text.innerText = "event 2";
  }

}
```

```html
<select id="events" onchange="myFunction(this)">
  <option value="Major">Major Events</option>
  <option value="Event1">1st event</option>
  <option value="Event2">2nd event</option>
</select>
<p id="text"></p>
```

While the above works, I suggest that you handle the event handling in your JS (as it is something which should be handled JS, not html). To do this, you can use `.addEventListener('change', fn)` to add an event listener within your JS:

```js
var events = document.getElementById('events'); // make sure the DOM has loaded before accessing this
var text = document.getElementById("text");

events.addEventListener('change', myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  var event = this.value; // get the value of the select option
  console.log(event);
  if (event === "Major") {
    text.innerText = "majorevents";
  } else if (event === "Event1") {
    text.innerText = "event 1";
  } else if (event === "Event2") {
    text.innerText = "event 2";
  }

}
```

```html
<select id="events">
  <option value="Major">Major Events</option>
  <option value="Event1">1st event</option>
  <option value="Event2">2nd event</option>
</select>
<p id="text"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.it will helps you.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  var e = document.getElementById('events'); 
  var strText = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  text.innerHTML = strText
}
```

```html
<select id="events" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="Major">Major Events</option>
  <option value="Event1">1st event</option>
  <option value="Event2">2nd event</option>
</select>
<p id="text"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

With that for loop you always take the last option in the select element. what you can do is take the selected option value and then use switch to figure out which text you should put in the p element like below:

```
function myFunction() {
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  var events = document.getElementById('events'),
    event, i;
    var selectedItem = events.options[events.selectedIndex].value;

    switch(selectedItem){

            case "Major": 
                text.innerHTML = "majorevents";
                break;

            case "Event1": 
                text.innerHTML = "event 1";
                break;

            case "Event2": 
                text.innerHTML = "event 2";
                break;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.options[this.selectedIndex].text` as parameter of `myFunction()`: `myFunction(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text)` to pass the selected option text.

And set the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) of `<p id="text">` value:
`document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = evt;` where `evt` is your parameter value.

```js
function myFunction(evt) {
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = evt;
}
```

```html
<select id="events" onchange="myFunction(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text)">
  <option value="Major">Major Events</option>
  <option value="Event1">1st event</option>
  <option value="Event2">2nd event</option>
</select>
<p id="text"></p>
```